# Error when running .bat file in Python subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

That is my script:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Z0176880\\TRAINING\\folder')
#os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Z0176880\\TRAINING\\folder')
subprocess.Popen(['program.bat'], cwd='C:\\Users\\Z0176880\\TRAINING\\folder')
```

When I use *subprocess.Popen()* to run my .bat program, the error appears. It says that

```
> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I use *sys.path.append()* and *cwd* parameter in Popen to add directory to the program, but it does not help. Only when I use *os.chdir()* it runs with no problem. It is worth mentioning that script as well as .bat are included in same folder. Could you explain me why it happens?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFKss.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) strongly recommend to use a "fully qualified path for the executable", since its resolution varies depending on the platform:

```
path= 'C:\\Users\\Z0176880\\TRAINING\\folder\\'
subprocess.Popen([path+'program.bat'])
```

However, if for some reason the `subprocess.Popen` version with given `cwd` shall be used, the following solution works at least on Windows:

```
subprocess.Popen(['program.bat'], cwd=path, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I think that sys.path.append() may not work because these are paths for import. However I consider why os.chdir() works while cwd in Popen does not.

Comment: As the Docs say for Popen: "when resolving or searching for the executable path with shell=False, cwd does not override the current working directory". Chdir, on the other hand _does_ change the working directory.